# VIm - find and replace pipe character

Tags: vim

Is there a way to find and replace pipe characters in Vim?

Here's my sample text:

```
'C1' | 'A1' | 'A2' |
```

I believe the pipe character is used to string together multiple searches, so I tried escaping it like this:

```
:%s/\|/,/g
```

This is what I get:

```
,',C,1,', ,|, ,',A,1,', ,|, ,',A,2,', ,|
,
```

This is my desired result:

```
'C1' , 'A1' , 'A2' ,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there.

The pipe character do not need to be escaped:

```
:%s/|/,/g
```

The result is exactly as you asked for:

```
'C1' , 'A1' , 'A2' ,
```

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: Understood, removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
:%s/|/,/g
```

Search for `|`, replace it with `,`

Comment: It is missing one space before the comma in the substitution to achieve the desired result.